Error al usar TCPDF symfony
Estoy creando un pdf en symfony, para ello uso TCPDF. En local todo me funciona perfecto, pero al subirlo al servidor de produccion, deja de funcionar y salta este error:
Attempted to load class "TCPDF" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?
use TCPDF; está incluido en el código, puede ser un error en el namespace? Este estoy usando: namespace App\Controller;
(es mi primer "proyecto grande" en symfony, no se usar muy bien los namespace)
Está definido en el composer.json, en la carpeta packages no hay nada. Y en el vendor  también están los archivos. Subí los archivos con filezilla, no me dió ningún error. Lo que no entiendo es que funcione en local pero no en el servidor.

Hola. ¿Podrías mostrar todo lo que tienes definido en tu archivo composer.json con respecto a TCPDF? ¿En la carpeta packages de tu proyecto tienes también algo definido al respecto? ¿En la carpeta vendor (en el servidor remoto) tienes los archivos relativos a TCPDF? ¿Podrías explicar de qué forma subiste los archivos a producción, si usando herramientas como Deployer u otras? Dinos también si al momento del despliegue no te avisó de ningún error. Pulsa en [edit] para agregar cualquier información adicional.
